# Using fast query in Sitecore Services Client RESTful API

Tags: sitecore-services-client, itemservice

Is there any to use the fast query in Sitecore Services Client API? (Sitecore 9.0.1)

I need to find an item with a particular name within a specific location and based on specific template. I'm able to use the below fast query:
**fast:/sitecore/content/home/folderitem//*[@@templateid='templateid'and @@name='itemname']**
This works perfectly.

But now I have to retrieve the same from a different instance. So opt for ItemService API.
How can I achieve the same fast query in the ItemService API ?

Comment: Are you sure you really need a FAST query to achieve this? Read this and maybe you can save your server in the future: https://intothecloud.blog/2018/10/21/It-s-time-to-put-fast-query-to-rest/.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Sitecore 9+, so you can use Odata item service to achieve this. By default there are various search options available in Odata service.

In your case the Odata request should be having the below filters.

```
/sitecore/content/home/folderitem?$filter=Name eq 'itemname' and TemplateName eq 'templatename'
```

have a look at the Sitecore [document](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-odata-item-service.html)